Problem in understanding how to find posterior (logistic regression)
I have got a question that I am not sure how to answer on it, and I would like to get some clarification, or to point me out where is the problem in my understanding.
We got a logistic regression problem where we need to find an optimal threshold $\theta$ based on measurement data (above the threshold the product will be supported and below it, it will be abandoned):
The random variable Z is for "success"(1) and "failure"(0), and the observations $X$ believe to come from $Gamma(2.5,0.25)$. The probability of success given $X=x$ is
$$
\Pr(Z=1 | X=x) = \frac{\exp((x-\mu)e^{-\gamma})}{1+\exp((x-\mu)e^{-\gamma})}
$$
where $\mu,\gamma$ are unknown parameters with flat priors.
I am now supposed to find an expression for the logarithm of the posterior densities of $\mu,\gamma$, but I am not sure how.
I thought about:
$$
f_{\mu|X=x}(\mu_0) = \frac{f_{X|\mu=\mu_0}(x)f_{\mu}(\mu_0)}{f_X(x)}
$$
and given that the prior of $\mu$ is some constant, and $f_X$ has gamma density, then the posterior should look something like
$$
\log(\frac{f_{X|\mu=\mu_0}(x)}{f_X(x)}) + C = \log(f_{X|\mu=\mu_0}(x)) - \log(f_X(x)) + C
$$
Where C is some additive constant based on the prior of $\mu$.
On the other hand, I want to say that $\mu$ and $X$ are independent, which brings the whole expression to just a constant, but I am not sure it's correct.
I am kind of stuck here, and would like to understand what I am missing.
Thanks.
